# When cell 1 in Column A is at 50% change cell 2 in the B column to "In Progress"

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find a way to add status to my project automatically. For example, when cell 1 in Column A is at 50% then i would want to change cell 2 in the B column to "In Progress". Is this possible in Excel?

please let me know.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't require VBA (although I can explain it if you're curious). I reccomend using nested IF formulas for this type of thing. Start with the case that covers others. When the statement is false, instead of giving an answer, you can give another IF statement as an answer.

```
=IF(A1=100;"completed";IF(A1<100;"In progress";"Cannot be superior to 100!"))
'IF(A1=100; true ^    ; False ^ starts another IF
```

This way you can add as many as you want! You can add an option to write "Not started yet" if it is =0, as you can see I added that it could not be higher than 100 myself. If it isnt =100, and isn't lower, then it must be higher, right? I got it covered. You can also cover for negative numbers, whatever you like! Just add more IF statements.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. A simple formula will do

```
=IF(A1=0.5, "In Progress", "")
```

This assumes that 50% is stored as 0.5.  You can also do `>=` if that makes more sense.

Comment: thanks. But how do i also add if A1 is less than 99 "In progress" and 100 is "completed"?

Comment: `=IF(A1<=99,"In progress","Completed")`